# Errors running script from command window MATLAB but not from run icon

Tags: matlab, function, loops, user-interface

I have a function file which contains a GUI.

Whenever I run (compile) the file using the green run logo in MATLAB it successfully builds. Whenever I try to run it from the command window i.e: `run(MyFile);`I get this error but the file still builds correctly:

```
??? Error using ==> fileparts at 31
Input must be a row vector of characters.

Error in ==> run at 25
[p,s,ext] = fileparts(script);
```

I'm not getting the error when I hit 'run' in the text editor.

Thoughts?

Comment: try `dbstop if error` and check what datatype `script` is.

Comment: `31      error(message('MATLAB:fileparts:MustBeChar'));`

Was what I got when I typed: `dbstop if error; run(MyFile);` in the command window

Comment: If matlab stops at the error, check what `script` is. Should be some file path (`char`)

Comment: What do you mean by check what `script` is? Sorry, new to MATLAB. Where would I look?

Comment: you could simply type `whos script` at the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work this way:

```
runtmp = fullfile('foldername','filename.m');
run(runtmp);
```

notice that the 'run' command executes scripts not currently on the MATLAB path. However, you should use **cd** or **addpath** to navigate to or to add the appropriate folder, making a script executable by entering its name alone.
The other point is run changes to the folder that contains the script, executes it, and resets back to the original folder. If the script itself changes folders, then run does not revert to the original folder, unless scriptname changes to the folder in which this script resides.

for more information check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html#runexam1).